# Is it possible for a Django template to test for existence of a row in a table without writing a custom tag/filter?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
    (etc.)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    (etc.)

class PostFollow(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='follower_set')
    follower = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='follower_set')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    an_arbitrary_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    (etc.)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('post', 'follower',)
```

In my template, I'd like to render a list of posts along with a "follow" or "unfollow" link so that the current user can decide whether to follow a given post. In a world where I could use arguments in Django templating, I'd do something like this:

```
{% for post in post_set %}
    <...stuff...>
    {% if post.user_is_following user %}unfollow{% else %}follow{% endif %}
    <...more stuff...>
{% endfor %}
```

However, I can't do that. And I can't make a zero-argument, template-callable method on any of these models, because they all need to know at least one other argument to answer the question whether a given PostFollow row exists in that table.

I'm happy to write a templating extension, but before I bring out the big guns, is this an appropriate case for doing so? Or is there a more Djangoesque solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Template filters are not big guns:

```
# your_app/templatetags/following.py 

from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def is_followed_by(post, user):
   return post.is_followed_by(user)
```

and then:

```
{% load following %}
...
{% if post|is_followed_by:user %} ... {% endif %}
```

You can also put all logic in template filter, remove 'post.is_followed_by' method and use the filter instead of model method just like any other function, @register.filter decorator doesn't harm the decorated function.

Comment: s/login/logic/

Thanks, Mike. I'd already written my own after I posted, but whenever I'm considering a hook, I want to make sure I'm not racing past a built-in solution. (I'd vote you up but I'm apparently too new to do so.)

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer. My question was asking to confirm that there wasn't any needle in this haystack, and since it's hard to prove a negative, I'll take the answer as sufficient evidence that there's no needle.